# Remove multiple items from your cart with just one click

Tags: magento2, php, cart, remove

In the Magento 2 cart when you click on the basket you can only remove one product from the cart. What I would like to do is to be able to remove multiple items from the cart at the same time as soon as I click on a single basket.

As shown in the example below, if I have two or more items in my cart, if I click on a single basket I would like more items to be removed.
[image]

I tried to do it with jquery like this but without success:

```
<script>
$("#shopping-cart-table .deleteItem .action-delete").on('click',function(){
                        $("#shopping-cart-table .deleteItem .action-delete").each(function(i) {
                            var btn = $(this);
                            
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                btn.trigger("click");
                            }, 100);
                            
                        });
                    });
</script>
```

How could I do fro remove multiple items from cart when i click only on remove button?

Comment: Are you saying you want to empty your cart? or you want to delete 2 out 3 items for instance..? but in the latter case, what is your business rule?

Comment: I want to delete two out of three articles for example, that's right.
My rule is: "When I click the remove button a simple product and a virtual product that have the same attribute value must be removed from cart."

Answer (score 1):

ok, it is quite complex but the structure should be:

1. you need to add a custom controller
2. you need to call this custom route and the controller will call the quote session model and browse its items and remove them if relevant. When the whole operation is complete, you may call collectTotals on the quote
3. when the controller response is successful, you will need to refresh the cart and this requires knowledge of uiComponent/customer-data and both are not trivial

One by one, all the points above do have a lot of questions/answers that you will find no doubts; you should be able to work your way through. Event the last point has some answers.. good luck

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have tried this method several times and it does not always work well because it creates problems for those with slow connections.
I noticed that when you quickly click on all the baskets of items in the Magento cart I remove all items correctly with just one page refresh.

Is there any way to invoke the original Magento $block->getDeletePostJson() method for multiple articles that have the same attribute value?

Comment: enable the cache is your answer :-)

Comment: yes I have always enabled the cache but some customers who have slow PCs had problems in these types of operations. There is an alternative? Thanks

Comment: Get a small linode server for $30/month and it should be fast enough

Comment: I am on a super fast Amazon server. The problem persists for some customers with slow connections

Comment: Just get your site validated as to why it is slow.. although Magento is slow, with a relevant server to your catalog, sales data and modules that works well, your site should perform.. Unfortunately, it is not something helpful but nothing we can comment unless we know the site in the first place. Having said this, it looks like what you describe as being slow is the javascript and in which case, it may be jquery is overused..

Comment: Speaking in terms of jQuery, is it not possible to simulate clicking on the various baskets of items in the cart at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

magento default supports this feature, it is called **Clear Shopping Cart**, but it is hidden by default.

For magento version >= 2.4.1, you can config it in Admin menu > Stores > Configuration > **Sales** > Checkout > **Shopping Cart** group > **Enable Clear Shopping Cart** field.

For magento version < 2.4.1, you have to display it by CSS:

```
.checkout-cart-index .form-cart .cart .action.clear {
    display: block
}
```